# Picklist field "Rating_score_c" and another text field name is "Rating_Grade_c"

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist

If I choose Picklist Field name is

**Rating_Score_c** (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9) then in  another field **Rating_Grade_c** show the grade A,B,C. ie.,
means

when i choose/pick any number (1,2,3) then it shows "A" in "Rating_Grade_c",

when i choose/pick any number (4,5,6) then it shows "B" in "Rating_Grade_c".

when i choose/pick any number (7,8,9) then it shows "C" in "Rating_Grade_c".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to your custom object. Click on **Field Dependancies** on **Custom.
- Fields & Relationships** section. Click **New** Choose **Controlling
- Field** and **Dependent Field** as you need. i.e.`Rating_Score_c` is
  controlling and `Rating_Grade_c` is dependent.
- After all in **Edit Field Dependancy** view set whatever values you needed on each controlling field selection.